# .Net Visual Studio In order to add Docker Support, the solution file (.sln) must be located in some folder or a hirer folder than ... error

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a project with include some microservices inside it. I add docker files to this microservices an configured it. (There is docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml  files on the root  also.)
My problem is this :

- If I delete Docker File of "Products" Microservice and then I use Add > Docker Support, Visual Studio is adding new Docker File (there is no problem)
- **But If I delete Docker File of "Sourcing" microservice,  Visual Studio not adding Docker file after Add > Docker Support  (I cant adding this file after delete)**

This two microservice is added  to project with same. There are same, but i can delete and re-add just one of them. I cant another. (For test, I added blank Core API solution to a folder and after i tried to add Dockerfile in this new project, but i saw same error.. )

How can i solve this mistake?

[image]